# Hibernate Database View with Annotations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I just tried to create a DB View using Hibernate Annotaions which looks like this

```
@Entity
@Subselect(value = "SELECT id, [..] FROM [] WHERE [..]")
@Synchronize({ "t1", "t2", "t3" })
public class SomeViewImpl implements SomeView {

    @Id
    protected String id;
[..]
```

Then I added it to the list of annotated classes in the sessionFactory (I'm using Spring) and try to run it.

I got no error and nothing, but the View is not created on the DB (actually a PostreSQL). Despite that I was not able to find something like that in the documentation, it may be that Hibernate is not supposed to create views in the DBs.

So the question I have: Is there a way to force Hibernate to create a View in my DB?

Comment: I think hibernate will not automatically create view for you in the database.

Comment: May you should add the "@Immutable" unless you have an "updateable view".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to let Hibernate create Views for you on the DB.
Our solution was to create the view manually on the DB